# Warning: mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in json

Tags: php, mysql, json

i got an error in my json codelike this,.

ERROR:

Warning: mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in D:\XAMPP\xampp\htdocs\ROOPA\music\demo.php on line 15
{"result":null}

PHP FILE:

```
<?php

 @include("db.php");


  $query = "SELECT a.a_name as name,b.total_value as value,b.total_votes as votes,a.a_pic as image FROM _album a inner join ratings b on b.a_id=a.id"; 

  $result = mysql_query($query);

//  $query1 = "SELECT total_value,total_votes FROM ratings";

  //$result1 = mysql_query($query1);

  $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
    //$count1 = mysql_num_rows($result1);

   if($count > 0)
    {

        while($data = mysql_fetch_object($result))
         {
              $alb_name =$data->name; 

              $rate_value = $data->value;

              $rate_votes = $data->votes;

              $alb_pic =$data->image; 

              $resmsg[] = array("Album_name"=>$alb_name,"Rating_total_value"=>$rate_value,"Rating_total_votes"=>$rate_votes,"Image_name"=>$alb_pic);

         }

        $jsonarr = array("result"=>$resmsg);
    }
    else
    {
        $jsonarr = array("result"=>"data not found");
    }

 echo json_encode($jsonarr);

?>
```

MY DB.PHP FILE:

```
<?php

$hostname="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$database="musicalbum";

$conn=mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password,$database);
$link=mysql_select_db($database,$conn);

if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
@mysql_close($link);

?>
```

CAN ANYONE HELP ME?

Comment: did you tried mysql_error() ? like this...

    if (!$result) {
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }

Comment: The obvious reason is either your database connection is failing OR your query is failing. Remove the error suppuration sign from include statement.

Comment: to get warned about sql error,try this which helps to find out sql error

if (!$result)
 die("mySQL error: ". mysql_error());

Comment: @shuvo - thanks u so much .. i got where i did error..

Comment: so ? what was your error... write here so it could be helpful for somebody with similar problem.

Comment: i did b.a_id=a.id instead a.a_id=b.id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue in below part of query:

```
inner join ratings b on b.a_id=a.id"
```

From your query, i guess a_[some_text] are columns of table a, but your query joins on a_id from table b. I think, it should be as below:

```
inner join ratings b on a.a_id=b.id"
```